# How to transform an array of [x: x1, y: y1] to an array of numbers where the numbers are stored like [x1, y1, x2, y2....] in javascript?

Tags: arrays, typescript, javascript-objects

I have an array which looks like:

```
const arr = [1,2,3,4,5,6]
```

I want to convert this array to look something like

```
const arr2 = [ {x: 1, y, 2}, {x:3, y:4}, {x:5, y:6}]
```

I have tried something like this:

```js
let res: any = [];
const arr = [1,2,3,4,5,6]
for (let i = 0; i < arr.length / 2; i++) {
  let next = 0
  res.push({x : arr[i + next], y : arr[i+1+next]})
  next += 2;
}

console.log(res);
```

But this doesnt give me the correct results.

Comment: The array variable's declaration is not valid js: use `let res = [];` instead.

Comment: Sorry I have should have mentioned this is typescript

Answer (score 1):

```js
const arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]
var result = [];

for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i += 2) {
  result.push({
    x: arr[i],
    y: i + 1 < arr.length ? arr[i + 1] : undefined
  })
}
console.log(result)
```

Comment: premature optimizations.

Comment: It's a 50% edge case.

Comment: I was talking about putting `null` or `0` instead of undefined. Also, we're making assumptions about how they want to treat that case. Maybe you want to throw an error or you want to put only the `x` coordinate

Comment: Idk. I couldn't leave `arr[i+1]` to chance. And "premature optimizations"? Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

```js
convertToPoints = (arr) => {
    let arr2 = [];

    // if arr does not contain an even amount of elements, return false
    if (arr.length % 2 !== 0) {
        return false;
    }
    
    for (let i = 0; i < arr.length - 1; i += 2) {
        arr2.push({ x: arr[i], y: arr[i+1] });
    }

    return arr2;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could get pairs of sliced arrays and create new objects with short hand properties.

```js
const
    array = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6],
    result = [];

let i = 0;
while (i < array.length) {
    const [x, y] = array.slice(i, i += 2);
    result.push({ x, y });
}

console.log(result);
```

A better approach with a simple loop.

```js
const
    array = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6],
    result = [];

for (let i = 0; i < array.length; i += 2) {
    result.push({ x: array[i], y: array[1 + 1] });
}

console.log(result);
```

Comment: That makes an awful lot of arrays. Just access by index

Comment: slice method called so many times is soo bad for performaance

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with reduce

```
arr.reduce((acc,curr,index) => {
    if(index % 2) { 
        acc[acc.length-1].y = curr
        return acc
    }
    return acc.concat({x:curr})
}, [])
```

Answer (score 0):

You can join the numbers and then group the coordinates by using a Regexp along with the function `String.prototype.match`.

```js
const arr = [1,2,3,4,5,6],
      result = arr.join("")
            .match(/([0-9]{2})/g)
            .map(coordinates => coordinates.split(""))
            .map(([x, y]) => ({x, y}));

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 0):

You got the index computation wrong.

```js
let res: any = [];
const arr = [1,2,3,4,5,6]
for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i += 2) {
  res.push({x : arr[i], y : arr[i+1]})
}

console.log(res);
```